# grep wildcards inside file

Tags: grep, wildcard

I am using the following code to filter SPAM on my mail server:

```
if 822field from | grep -qiFf "/email_filters/from.txt"; then exit 99; fi
```

and also:

```
if 822field subject | grep -qiFf "email_filters/bad_subject.txt"; then exit 99; fi
```

Inside of the two above-referenced files, I have lists of SPAM email sources and subjects (e.g., pfizer, cialis, viagra, etc.), each on its own line in the text file.

How can I have wildcards within the file? For example, I have recently begun receiving fake U.S. Postal Service notifications from 
status_38@unikmetal.ru", so I'd like to block "@**_**.ru".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `-F` to grep, it processes a fixed string not a regular expression.  To use wildcards you must use regular expressions as far as I know.

Remove the `-F` in the `grep` command

```
grep -qif "/email_filters/from.txt"
```

To block your russian email addresses you can add something like this to your filters

```
@.*\.ru
```

Explanation

```
@ - match '@' character literally
.* - match any character 0 or more times
\. - match '.' literally
ru - match 'ru' literally
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the complete explanation.